# Codeigniter / Eloquent selecting but not inserting

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, insert, eloquent

I've followed [this](https://marceau.casals.fr/blog/2015/02/utiliser-eloquent-orm-avec-codeigniter) (french) and [this](http://jamieonsoftware.com/post/90299647695/using-eloquent-orm-inside-codeigniter-with-added) tutorials to use Eloquent in CodeIgniter 3 application.

The selection methods work as expected, even with relationships, but the inserting / updating methods are not working and not returning any error either. I've search for similar problems but couldn't solve mine, so I hope someone can help me on this.

One of my model :

```
<?php

require_once('Eloquent.php');

use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent { 

    //Eloquent vars
    public $table = "app_users";
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

An insertion that returns 1 but isn't actually inserting the data into the db :

```
  $client = new User;
  $client->id = $id;
  $client->username = 'username';
  $client->first_name = 'first_name';
  $client->last_name = 'last_name';
  $client->mail = 'mail';
  $result = $client->save();
```

The insertion silently fails... any hint would be much appreciated, whether about how to solve this or to debug it! Once again the find(), all(), etc methods are working fine, so Eloquent seems to function properly...

Comment: So which method are you actually using to establish the connection. The french version seems to create the PDO connection manually. In this case the you might need to set the exception mode: `$pdosetAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` - The default is `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` - (see [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php))

Comment: What PHP errors say (fifteen chars)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Paul Spiegel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5563083/paul-spiegel) for pointing out that I needed to modify the exception mode (I was missing a database migration which was making the insertion/update failing)